# Is it possible to build Android apps without Java?

Tags: java, android, c++, python, django

I want to learn how to how to program apps for Android. I am not very fond of Java. I read that you could build Android apps with Python and C++. So can I build apps completely without using Java? Also what are the advantages of C++, Python, and Java when building Android? Another question: Will Django Framework work for Android? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to checkout the likes of Phonegap, Scala, Groovy, Mirah, Rhodes, Clojure

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible but I don't think that'll be an easy way

if you want to use python you can use python wrapper here -> https://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/ it built together with Scripting Layer for android (https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/)

if you want to use C++ you can use android NDK and JNI that provided from google SDK this one is a good example if you want to learn -> https://code.google.com/p/cgroupmgr/wiki/JNIBasics

but in the end I think you should learn java to code android :) because with that you can fully understand and take advantage of android SDK